# How to hide google Script activity in google Site recent changes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

My google-apps-script is regularly updating the content of my google site List page. Every entry it deletes or adds is added to the "recent changes" of the website, making this list useless, cluttered with "you deleted/added an item to list...".

Is there a way to prevent the logging of these modifications by the script, exclude that particular page from the recent changes listing, or exclude the actions of a given user to be recorded (or displayed)?

Any suggestions would be appreciated,
Thanks.
Berteh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to prevent these changes from showing up.

Answer (score 0):

manage site -> general tab, option is at very bottom, perhaps its a new change. You can specify who can see the recent site activity and revision changes and set it to collaborators (people allowed to edit the site) only, so it is not visible to public.

Comment: thanks. good to know. It does not solve my problem of not recording the log, but at least gives some control on displaying them.